# Fetch just once with Redux then load from store

Tags: json, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

On server I have JSON schema, which serves me for gathering enums or min/max. The data are then displayed in forms or somewhere else.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(genders());
    this.props.dispatch(races());
    this.props.dispatch(ages());
  }
```

In every function (genders, races, ages) is something like this:

```
export const genders = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(requestedProperty('genders'));
  dispatch(schema())
    .then(schema => dispatch(receivedProperty('genders', schema.properties.general.properties.gender.enum)));
};
```

Where schema function is accessing the JSON schema as follow:

```
const schema = (method = 'GET') => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(requestedSchema(method.toUpperCase()));
  return axios.get(`schema/v1/demand/${method.toLowerCase()}.json`)
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch(receivedSchema(response.data));
      return response.data;
    });
};
```

There are multiple requests for the single file. I would like to download the file just once and store content to Redux store. Then, I would like to access the received data via `getState`.

I have tried pass `getState` to `schema` function and download the file just in case I have nothing in Redux store yet, but I'm getting empty object every time.

For completeness I have this reducer:

```
export const schema = (state = { fetching: false }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUESTED_DEMAND_SCHEMA:
      return { ...state, fetching: true };
    case RECEIVED_DEMAND_SCHEMA:
      return { ...state, schema: action.schema, fetching: false };
    case RECEIVED_DEMAND_SCHEMA_PROPERTY:
      return { ...state, [action.property]: action.value };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

What pattern should I use for this particular problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, I would start with something like this:

```
// Demographics/container.js

const mapStateToProps = {}

const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
  fetchDemographics,
}

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)

// api/genders/get.js

const getGenders = async () =>  {
  // your fetch/axios logic
  // return responseData
}

// Demographics/thunks.js

const fetchGenders = () => async (dispatch, getState) {
  dispatch(request('genders'))
  await getGenders() 
  dispatch(receive('genders'))
}

export const fetchDemographics = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  await Promise.all([
    dispatch(fetchGenders()),
    dispatch(fetchRaces()),
    dispatch(fetchAges()),
  ])
}

// Request/reducer.js
const request = (value = '') => ({
  type: 'REQUEST',
  value: '',
})

const receive = (value = '') => ({
  type: 'RECEIVE',
  value: '',
})

export default = (state = { fetching: false }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST:
      return { ...state, value: action.value, fetching: true };
    case RECEIVE:
      return { ...state, value: action.value, fetching: false };
    default:  
      return state;
  }
```

If the data for genders, race, and age can be fetched independently, you can use `Promise.all()` to kick off your request pipeline efficiently.

You can use thunks to manage your asynchronous calls and anything else i might have left out.

A generic 'request' reducer or the like should be sufficient enough to track outbound requests in your store.

Next, I would create a separate reducer to store the results of each schema.

```
// Schema/reducer.js
export default = (state = { genders: {}, race: {}, age: {} }}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
switch (action.type) {
  case UPDATE:
      return { ...state, [action.property]: action.schema };
  }
```

From here you could use redux `mapStateToProps` to access needed gender, race, or age data

Answer (score 0):

From your code example I was unsure where your "There are multiple requests for the single file" action was.

Have you tried ReduxThunk?
Inside thunk it would look like this.

```
export default store => next => action => {
  return typeof action === 'function'
    ? action(store.dispatch, store.getState)
    : next(action);
};
```